# How could I do PIL.ImageOps.solarize with opencv-python?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I tried this code but found that the colors are not same

```
from PIL import ImageOps
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(imgpth)
impil = np.array(im)
imcv = cv2.imread(imgpth)[:, :, ::-1].copy()
print(np.sum(imcv - impil))

impil_sol = np.array(ImageOps.solarize(im, threshold=128))
idx = imcv > 128
imcv_sol[idx] = 255 - imcv_sol[idx]
print(np.sum(impil_sol - imcv_sol))
```

The first output is 0 but the second is not 0. What does PIL.ImageOps.solarize exactly do and how could I do it with opencv-python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few errors and omissions in your given code; actually it doesn't even compile. Please pay attention to always provide a proper [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

First problem is, that `imcv_sol` isn't properly initialized. Second problem is, that the description of [`PIL.ImageOps.solarize`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageOps.html#PIL.ImageOps.solarize) seems to be wrong (highlighting by me):

> Invert all pixel values **above** a threshold.

Let's have a look at the following, modified code:

```py
import cv2              # Please provide all necessary imports
import numpy as np      # Please provide all necessary imports
from PIL import ImageOps
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('path/to/your/image.png')
impil = np.array(im)
imcv = cv2.imread('path/to/your/image.png')[:, :, ::-1]
print(np.sum(imcv - impil))

impil_sol = np.array(ImageOps.solarize(im, threshold=128))
imcv_sol = imcv.copy()  # imcv_sol was nowhere initialized?
idx = imcv >= 128       # threshold seems to be also incorporated, i.e. >= instead of > here
imcv_sol[idx] = 255 - imcv[idx]
print(np.sum(impil_sol - imcv_sol))
```

If I run that code for any image, I get the proper output:

```
0
0
```

If I switch to `idx = imcv > 128`, there are deviations.

You can check my assumption, if you have a look at all pixels with the given threshold, i.e. for example, fetch `ids = impil == 128`, and then inspect `impil_sol[ids]`. All values are `127`, so that (also) all pixels with value `128` must've been inverted, which is not reflected by the above description.

Hope that helps!